# dynamic/variable port mapping

Tags: docker-compose

We have a couple of Docker Images that run an Apache2 server, and we scrape data from them using prometheus:

Docker-compose file (minimal):

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  noteable:
    image: naas/noteable
    ports:
      - 9118:9117

  proxy:
    image: /naas/noteable_proxy
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 9117:9117
```

In this format, both services are exposing prometheus data on port `9117`, which is then mapped to *different* ports on the host.

If I try to scale the `noteable` service, I get a port clash:

```
[naas@naas-dev ~]$ docker-compose up --no-recreate --scale noteable=2
Starting naas_proxy_1 ... 
WARNING: The "noteable" service specifies a port on the host. If multiple containers for this service are created on a single host, the port will clash.
Starting naas_noteable_1 ... done
Creating naas_noteable_2 ... error

ERROR: for naas_noteable_2  Cannot start service noteable: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint naas_noteable_2 (47ff958b454ce75887ea4a2b8f1b42f8618dc04f3911fa9190fb27129443728a): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9118 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for noteable  Cannot start service noteable: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint naas_noteable_2 (47ff958b454ce75887ea4a2b8f1b42f8618dc04f3911fa9190fb27129443728a): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9118 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

(which is kinda obvious, really)

Question: Is there some clever way to do `9117+:9117` (ie, "map to 9117, or the next available port thereafter")?